# How long banks in India retain transaction details?

Tags: india, banking

How long does banks in India need to retain the transaction details for a savings account?
For a legal requirement to prove that I've made payment to someone in the Year 2003, I'm looking for that years statement. As it has been a while now I'm not able to download the statement.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do it online. Better is to get in touch with your bank. But I don't assume it will be for free.

Comment: Banks don't even give current statements for free, it always comes with a fee. Approaching the bank didn't yield a result.

Comment: `Approaching the bank didn't yield a result` Then it cannot happen if the bank itself isn't going to provide you with the statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The retention schedule for financial transactions is 7 years from memory... let me see if I can back this up